# computing a hash in NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, hash, nasm

I need help understanding these instructions regarding a program I have to do in NASM assembly

> The hash value will be 5 bytes long. The first word will be the sum of all the most significant nibbles in the file, after applying rotate to the right. The high order nibbles will be rotated by a value starting with zero and incrementing each time. After reaching the value of 7 the rotate counter should start back at zero.The second word will be the sum of all the least significant nibbles in the file after applying rotate to the right. The low order nibbles will be rotated by a value starting with 3. The final byte will be the XOR of all the bytes in the file

What I'm confused about is how to imagine counting the most and least significant nibbles.

so if I have a file with 2 characters: AB

A - **0100** 0001
B - **0100** 0010
would be my ***most*** significant nibbles

A - 0100 **0001**
B - 0100 **0010**
would be my ***least*** significant nibbles

How am I suppose to rotate and count these, given the specific instructions, without getting the nibbles out of order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I suppose to rotate and count these, given the specific
>   instructions, without getting the nibbles out of order?

You'll have to copy bytes to different registers, where you shift and mask to do 4-bit rotates.  The x86 rotate instructions are only available with 8, 16, 32, and 64bit operand sizes.  (And 9, 17, 32, 65, if you count the slow rotate-with-carry instructions.)